# jQuery Carousel (CarouFredSel) stop animation if only 3 images

Tags: jquery, if-statement, carousel, caroufredsel

OK, slightly complex question. I have a carousel on my page (using CarouFredSel plugin) sometimes this carousel will have 3 images in it, sometimes 4 or more. The carousel is set to display 3 images at a time, with the center image being larger.

My issue is this, if I only have 3 images, I can't slide the carousel left and right in order to make the adjacent images central (and therefore larger). To get around this I add a dummy image (i.e. just write `<img src="" />` so the slider thinks there are 4 images, this allows me to slide, however, I want to be able to stop the slider before getting to the 4th 'dummy' image.

My HTML is as follows:

```
<div id="wrapper">
        <div id="carousel">
            <img src="http://www.samskirrow.com/client-kateguest/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Christmas.jpg" />
            <img src="http://www.samskirrow.com/client-kateguest/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Birds.jpg" />
            <img src="http://www.samskirrow.com/client-kateguest/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/christmas_alt2.jpg" />
            <img src="" />

        </div>
            <a id="prev2" class="prev" href="#">&lt;</a>
            <a id="next2" class="next" href="#">&gt;</a>
    </div>
```

and jQuery for the slider plugin:

```
$(function() {

            var _center = {
                width: 275,
                height: 390,
                marginLeft: 0,
                marginTop: 0,
                marginRight: 0
            };
            var _left = {
                width: 140,
                height: 200,
                marginLeft: 0,
                marginTop: 100,
                marginRight: 20
            };
            var _right = {
                width: 140,
                height: 200,
                marginLeft: 20,
                marginTop: 100,
                marginRight: 0
            };
            var _outLeft = {
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                marginLeft: 150,
                marginTop: 200,
                marginRight: -150
            };
            var _outRight = {
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                marginLeft: 0,
                marginTop: 200,
                marginRight: 0
            };
            $('#carousel').carouFredSel({
                auto: false,
                prev: {
                    button: "#prev2",
                    key: "left"
                },
                swipe: true,
                width: 597, 
                height: 392,
                align: false,
                items: {
                    visible: 3,
                    width: 100
                },

                next: {
                    button: "#next2",
                    key: "right",
                    items: 1,
                    duration: 400,
                    onBefore: function( data ) {
                        data.items.old.eq( 0 ).animate(_outLeft);
                        data.items.visible.eq( 0 ).animate(_left).removeClass('center right').addClass('left');
                        data.items.visible.eq( 1 ).animate(_center).addClass('center').removeClass('right left');
                        data.items.visible.eq( 2 ).animate(_right).css({ zIndex: 1 }).removeClass('left center').addClass('right');
                        data.items.visible.eq( 2 ).next().css(_outRight).css({ zIndex: 0 });

                        setTimeout(function() {
                            data.items.old.eq( 0 ).css({ zIndex: 1 });
                            data.items.visible.eq( 0 ).css({ zIndex: 2 });
                            data.items.visible.eq( 1 ).css({ zIndex: 3 });
                            data.items.visible.eq( 2 ).css({ zIndex: 2 });
                        }, 200);
                    }
                },
                prev: {
                    button: "#prev2",
                    key: "left",
                    items: 1,
                    duration: 400,
                    onBefore: function( data ) {
                        data.items.old.eq( 2 ).animate(_outRight);
                        data.items.visible.eq( 0 ).animate(_left).css({ zIndex: 1 }).removeClass('center right').addClass('left');
                        data.items.visible.eq( 0 ).prev().css(_outLeft).css({ zIndex: 0 });
                        data.items.visible.eq( 1 ).animate(_center).addClass('center').removeClass('right left');
                        data.items.visible.eq( 2 ).animate(_right).removeClass('left center').addClass('right');

                        setTimeout(function() {
                            data.items.old.eq( 2 ).css({ zIndex: 1 });
                            data.items.visible.eq( 2 ).css({ zIndex: 2 });
                            data.items.visible.eq( 1 ).css({ zIndex: 3 });
                            data.items.visible.eq( 0 ).css({ zIndex: 2 });
                        }, 200);
                    }
                }
            });
            $('#carousel').children().eq( 0 ).css(_left).css({ zIndex: 2 }).addClass('left').removeClass('center right');
            $('#carousel').children().eq( 1 ).css(_center).css({ zIndex: 3 }).addClass('center').removeClass('right left');
            $('#carousel').children().eq( 2 ).css(_right).css({ zIndex: 2 }).addClass('right').removeClass('center left');
            $('#carousel').children().eq( 3 ).css(_outRight).css({ zIndex: 1 });
            $('#carousel').children().eq( 4 ).css(_outLeft).css({ zIndex: 1 });

        });
```

and here is a JSFiddle, so you can see what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/hvZzc/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add the minimum to your code:

"Minimum: Number The minimum number of items needed to create a carousel.
If null, the number for items.visible is inherited and increased by 1." ( from their [website](http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/configuration.php))

adding that tag to your code this one will look like:

```
            items: {
                visible: 3,
                minimum: 3,
                width: 100
            },
```

instead of:

```
            items: {
                visible: 3,
                width: 100
            },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hvZzc/2/

Comment: Thanks for this great answer. Any idea why when I click on next, the right image is out of view and small?

Comment: for some reason it's splitting the right image in 2. let me try few things and I'll let you know